# What is the best word to admire somebody's help and manner? worth or valuable?

Tags: word-choice

Assume that somebody tried to help me (he did his best), but he couldn't change anything. Now I want to thank him. which one of this sentences are better/correct?

> You tried to help me and this is really **valuable** for me?

or

> You tried to help me and this is really **worth** for me?

or? (any better words?)

Comment: Since the question is about expressing gratitude, it really depends on the nature of the help.  Someone who tries to help you remove your belongings from a house on fire, but fails, would deserve a different sort of thanks than someone who tries to make an idiom clear but doesn't quite succeed.

Comment: You could use *worthwhile* in the second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You tried to help and that **means a lot to me**.

Or:

> Although we weren't able to [...], I **appreciate your help**.

Or:

> Your help in this matter was **much appreciated**.

Comment: "Much appreciated" looks a bit odd doesn't it? I think it's an idiom.

Comment: Thank you dear mark.You tried to help and that means a lot to me. ;) Can I use "that means me a lot" instead of "that means a lot to me"? what is the difference?

Comment: No problem! Just to clarify: "Tried to help" implies I tried to help you and failed. If my suggestions DID help, you should say "Your help means a lot to me". Now, you can't say "That means me a lot" because "means a lot" is an idiom. It's not like saying "That helps me a lot".

Comment: Oops :) OK, Surely Your helped me :) and thank you again for the answer of my question in your comment. But If you let me I wait 24 hours before accepting your answer. I want to see other answers also. :)

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, happy to help!